# boost::asio::tcp two-way communication on a socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio`, `TCP communication` and `C++` to create a client and a server that talk over a `TCP socket`. I need both the client and the server to be able send and receive data to each other. I am able to make them communicate over a socket where the server is continuously sending some data and the client is continuously reading on the socket. It works.

**Now for the other way communication :** *For client to send some data and the server to be able to read it, can I use the same socket for this?  Or Do I need to use a separate socket? Is it possible to read and write on the same socket for two applications communicating over TCP?*

A boost::asio based example to illustrate this will be great if available. But I am able to find examples which are about only one-way communications.

Comment: What is wrong with the examples on the boost page? I would start of with the async echo server.

Comment: all the boost examples are around a client server approach. I am not sure if any of the examples demonstrate bi-directional communication. Checking the echo server example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > For client to send some data & server to be able to read it, can I use the same socket for this? Or Do I need to use a separate socket ? Is it possible to read and write on the same socket for two applications communicating over TCP ?

Yes. TCP is full duplex. Applications define the protocol of what/how messages are exchanged between client and server. Weather they do asynchronously or synchronously, TCP doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

The client server paradigm in tcp is one where the client initiates the connection and the server listens for incoming connections. Once tge connection is established, it is up to higher layer protocol like http to establish how data is exchanged. As far as tcp is concerned both client and server may send or receive data any way they choose. Tcp is full duplex.